# Partial rest updates

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Lets say I have `Order` resource, and an action `public ActionResult UpdateOrder(Order order)`. 
I am trying to make `REST` api. And I want to push this order to next status.

For this purpose I have a method named `ChangeOrderStatus(string newStatus, int orderId)` on backend which does everything about status change (send some mails, do logging, insert some things into DB. etc...) and that method will be called from controller action. The point is that changing order status is complex operation, not just replace old filed value with new one.

But my question is should I write new controller action (route) for status change, for instance `public ActionResult UpdateOrderStatus(string newStatus, int orderId)` and call `ChangeOrderStatus` there or I should put everything in `UpdateOrder(Order order)` method? For instance, part of the `UpdateOrder(Order order)` method in that case would be:

`if (order.Status != oldOrder.Status) {
    ChangeOrderStatus(order.Status, order.Id);
}`

I would do it with first approach, but some people tell me that the second approach is better, because there should be a single entry point for resource update, so my status update or any other update related to order resource should be in `UpdateOrder` method... So I am not sure what is the right approach...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to update an `OrderStatus` I would use a resource like `/orders/{id}/status`. The backing controller should be capable of handling all steps neccessary. It you would alter the items of an order, this would be `/orders/{id}/items` or `/orders/{id}/items/{id}` for a single one.

To update the Order itself this would got to `/orders/{id}`.